# Dynamic Text in Power BI - Measures to support the Text

Tags: powerbi, dax, measures

I want to create a dynamic text (Visual - Enlighten Data Story) that will write the measures X, Y and Z (see pictures below).

X is the Activity that had the most energy consumption on that city (one of those: Industry, Transports, Services, etc etc) Y is the value of that energy consumption Z is the percentage between Y and the Total consumption of that City

For this example, in the City of Porto that text should return:

> X = Edificios de Serviços Y = 589.976 Z = 49%

[image: example Porto]

If I select any other city, for example Guimarães:

> X = Industria Y = 428.726 Z = 59%

[image: example Guimarães]

Here is my table:

[image: table]

Looking forward for help. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your question? "I want a pony" is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. Important is to know the index of the values and Rank does that:

```
//Calculated column
Rank =
VAR City = Table1[City]
RETURN
    RANKX (
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[City] = City ),
        [Energy_Mwh],
        [Energy_Mwh],
        ASC,
        DENSE
    )

//Calculated field/measure
City-as Measure =
LASTNONBLANK ( Table1[City], 1 )

//Calculated field/measure
x = CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(Table1[Activity],1),filter(all(Table1[Rank]),Table1[Rank] = max(Table1[Rank])))

//Calculated field/measure
y = CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(Table1[Energy_Mwh],1),filter(all(Table1[Rank]),Table1[Rank] = max(Table1[Rank])))
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you sooo much! you are a life saver, that solution worked perfectly and did exactly what I wanted! =) I am still a begginner at Power BI, and I dont think I could ever do that by myself.

Comment: Thank you. Please also see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers